# Draw line animated

Tags: swift, animation, draw

I want to have a line in the center of the screen and animate it like a snake

This is step by step animation I want to make

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is your code for generating the line? Can you elaborate?

Comment: I've tried playing with shape layers and animating then and in case i'm asking for a help nothing succeeded

Comment: The code would be really helpful, since we don't read minds.

Comment: In iOS or macOS? FYI, even if your attempts didn't succeed, you should share what you tried.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You can animate the end of the stroke of a `path` on a `CAShapeLayer`, e.g.,

```
weak var shapeLayer: CAShapeLayer?

@IBAction func didTapButton(_ sender: Any) {
    // remove old shape layer if any

    self.shapeLayer?.removeFromSuperlayer()

    // create whatever path you want

    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 10, y: 50))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 200, y: 50))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 200, y: 240))

    // create shape layer for that path

    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.fillColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0).cgColor
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1).cgColor
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 4
    shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath

    // animate it

    view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
    animation.fromValue = 0
    animation.duration = 2
    shapeLayer.add(animation, forKey: "MyAnimation")

    // save shape layer

    self.shapeLayer = shapeLayer
}
```

That yields:

[image: stroked path]

Clearly, you can change the `UIBezierPath` to whatever suits your interests. For example, you could have spaces in the path. Or you don't even need to have rectilinear paths:

```
let path = UIBezierPath()
path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 10, y: 130))
path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 210, y: 200), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 50, y: -100), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 350))
```

You can also combine animation of both the start and end of the stroke in a `CAAnimationGroup`:

```
// create shape layer for that path (this defines what the path looks like when the animation is done)

let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
shapeLayer.fillColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0).cgColor
shapeLayer.strokeColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1).cgColor
shapeLayer.lineWidth = 5
shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
shapeLayer.strokeStart = 0.8

let startAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeStart")
startAnimation.fromValue = 0
startAnimation.toValue = 0.8

let endAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
endAnimation.fromValue = 0.2
endAnimation.toValue = 1.0

let animation = CAAnimationGroup()
animation.animations = [startAnimation, endAnimation]
animation.duration = 2
shapeLayer.add(animation, forKey: "MyAnimation")
```

Yielding:

[image]

CoreAnimation gives you a lot of control over how the stroked path is rendered.

Comment: How can I create two simultaneous animations?

Comment: If you're talking about doing multiple animations on the same layer, do it like my final example. If you're talking about animating different layers/views at the same time, just do it. If you tried something and it's not doing what you expected, post your own question showing us your code, describe/show what it achieved, and describe what you wanted to achieve.

Comment: Ok.  Done: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49593397/how-do-i-animate-two-views-simultaneously-in-swift-programmatically

Comment: `view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)`
Final line is missing.

Answer (score 4):

My need was something similar - wanted to let the motion of a shape trace a line in the scene, but was having great difficulty synchronizing animation in CAShapeLayer with animation in SKScene.

So ended up using a different approach:

```
import SpriteKit
import PlaygroundSupport
import AVFoundation

let start = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 50)
let end = CGPoint(x: 200, y: 50)
let control = CGPoint(x: 150, y: 100);
var motion: SKAction = SKAction();

let radius: CGFloat = 20;
let bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 200)
let skview = SKView(frame: bounds)
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = skview
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

class MyScene: SKScene,AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate {
    var motionComplete = false
    var redline: SKShapeNode = SKShapeNode();
    var greenball: SKShapeNode = SKShapeNode();
    override func sceneDidLoad() {

        greenball = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: radius);
        greenball.position = start;
        greenball.fillColor = .green;

        let motionpath = CGMutablePath();

        motionpath.move(to: start)
        motionpath.addQuadCurve(to: end, control: control)

        motion = SKAction.follow(motionpath, asOffset: false, orientToPath: true,duration: 2);

        let linepath = CGMutablePath();
        linepath.move(to: start);
        redline = SKShapeNode(path: linepath);
        redline.strokeColor = .red;
        redline.lineWidth = 5;

        greenball.run(motion) {
            self.motionComplete = true;
        };

        self.addChild(greenball);
        self.addChild(redline);
    }

    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {

        if (motionComplete == false) {
            let cgpath = self.redline.path as! CGMutablePath;
            cgpath.addLine(to: greenball.position);
            self.redline.path = cgpath;

        }
    }


}



let scene = MyScene(size: CGSize(width: 400, height: 200));
scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.aspectFill
scene.size = skview.bounds.size
skview.presentScene(scene)
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One method is using a UIView with the background color. 
Try something like this.

```
let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
let redLine = UIView()
redline.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
redLine.frame = GCRect(x: screenWidth / 2, y: screenHeight / 2, width: 0, height: 0)

UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, animations: {
    redLine.frame = GCRect(x: screenWidth / 2, y: screenHeight / 2, width: 0, height: (screenHeight / 2) - 4)
}) { finished in
    redLine.frame = GCRect(x: screenWidth / 2, y: (screenHeight / 2) - 4, width: 0, height: 1)
}
```

With this, you can achieve any amount of red line movement.

The other method is to actually draw a line. I won't go into detail about that, but would recommend [this article](https://medium.com/@nrewik/easy-line-drawing-animation-b56958bc2bee#.p82xbd1lk).

One last thing... On stack overflow we appreciate people who show they properly researched a topic before just asking a question. Using google, I was able to quickly come up with many tutorials on how to do what you are looking for. Try to do research yourself, because often a tutorial will have far more detail that is important than a stack overflow answer.

Answer (score 0):

This technique can also be used, its added as border you can mold it your way. First create a path and then draw lines on it accordingly

```
    let path = UIBezierPath()
```

i have given x, y values according to my need, you can change it according to yours

```
path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 134, y: 209))//
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: (131 + 93), y: 209))// for drawing line
    path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: (131 + 97), y: 212) , controlPoint: CGPoint(x: (131 + 93), y: 209))// for drawing a curve
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: (131 + 97) , y: (209 + 33 )))
    path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: (131 + 93), y: (209 + 37)), controlPoint:  CGPoint(x: (131 + 97) , y: (209 + 33 )))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 135, y: (209 + 37)))
    path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 131, y: 209 + 33), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: 135, y: 209 + 37))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 131, y: 213))
    path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 134, y: 209), controlPoint:CGPoint(x: 131, y: 213) )
     let shapelayer = CAShapeLayer()//create shape layer object
    shapelayer.fillColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0).cgColor
    shapelayer.strokeColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.06274510175, green: 0, blue: 0.1921568662, alpha: 1).cgColor
    shapelayer.lineWidth = 2
    shapelayer.path = path.cgPath
    view.layer.addSublayer(shapelayer)
    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")// create animation and add it to shape layer
    animation.fromValue = 0
    animation.duration = 3
    shapelayer.add(animation, forKey: "MyAnimation")
    self.shapelayer = shapelayer
```

That's all. Hope it can help someone, as i also achieved this after a few hours effort because didn't find the exact solution. check this link as well:

https://github.com/Shahijabeen/BorderAnimation