# How do I animate two views simultaneously in swift programmatically?

Tags: swift, animation

In another question, how to animate was answered: 
[Draw line animated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42978418/draw-line-animated/42978938?noredirect=1#comment86194055_42978938)

I then tried to add a view to animate simultaneously.  I want to create two animated paths that meet at the same  `CGPoint` but have different paths to get there.  I want both paths to start at the same time and end animation at the same time.  My current approach is to create a second `UIBezierPath` called path2, along with a second `CAShapeLayer` called `shapeLayer2`, but the second path is just overriding the first. I'm pretty sure both paths need different `CAShapeLayer`s because each path will have different attributes.  It seems like I then need to add the `CAShapeLayer` instance as a `view.layer` sublayer but it doesn't seem to be working.  What should I be doing differently to achieve the desired result?

Comment: You need a second `CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")` for `shapeLayer2`.

Comment: Ok, I added it.  Its animating one correctly but not showing the red path.  It's like when I add the sublayer, it overrides the first one.

Comment: neevermind, I see it. I gave the second shape layer the same path as the first.  I updated it to path2.

Comment: If that solves your problem, I'd suggest you just delete this question...

Comment: Yea, I can see how this would be confusing as is.  I can see this being useful to people that were in my situation.  I'm going to post the code as an answer.  Let me know if you still think I should delete it after that.

Comment: No, if you think the answer will be helpful for others, go for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what ultimately worked.

```
    func animatePath() {

    // create whatever path you want
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 10, y: 100))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 200, y: 50))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 200, y: 240))

    // create whatever path you want
    let path2 = UIBezierPath()
    let bottomStartX = view.frame.maxX - 10
    let bottomStartY = view.frame.maxY - 100
    path2.move(to: CGPoint(x: bottomStartX, y: bottomStartY))
    path2.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bottomStartX - 100, y: bottomStartY - 100))
    path2.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 200, y: 240))

    // create shape layer for that path
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.fillColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0).cgColor
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1).cgColor
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 4
    shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath

    let shapeLayer2 = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer2.fillColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0).cgColor
    shapeLayer2.strokeColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
    shapeLayer2.lineWidth = 4
    shapeLayer2.path = path.cgPath

    // animate it
    view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer2)
    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
    animation.fromValue = 0
    animation.duration = 2
    shapeLayer.add(animation, forKey: "MyAnimation")


    let animation2 = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
    animation2.fromValue = 0
    animation2.duration = 2
    shapeLayer2.add(animation2, forKey: "MyAnimation")

    // save shape layer
    self.shapeLayer = shapeLayer
}
```