# Line animation in rectangle with cornerRadius

Tags: swift, animation, cashapelayer, cakeyframeanimation

I need create line animation with constant length along rounded rectangle. 
So I stopped after creating needed BezierPath `UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 100, height: 100), cornerRadius: 5)` so next step what I need to do is to use `CAKeyframeAnimation` for animating line with width 45 along that path
Does someone could help me with that?

Comment: Do you want to animate the line drawing from start to end?

Comment: yes @RajeshKumarR, but problem is that line is 1/4 length of that path. Plus I need infinity repeated count

Comment: bet you will find answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42978418/draw-line-animated

Comment: @Kirow I am using `CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")`  and `CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "strokeStart")`. The main problem is that it's not looks like infinity its stopped when `strokeEnd = 0` because its could not be grater than 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, then. Use dash pattern instead of start/end. Suggest to use [this repo](https://github.com/louisdh/bezierpath-length)
to calculate cgPath length to make pattern you need.

```swift
let rectangle = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 500))
rectangle.clipsToBounds = true
rectangle.backgroundColor = .blue
rectangle.layer.cornerRadius = 50

let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rectangle.bounds, cornerRadius: 50)
let shape = CAShapeLayer()
shape.path = path.cgPath
shape.lineWidth = 10
shape.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor

shape.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
let length = path.cgPath.length
shape.lineDashPattern = [NSNumber(value: 45), NSNumber(value: Float(length - 45))]
rectangle.layer.addSublayer(shape)


let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "lineDashPhase")
animation.fromValue = 0
animation.toValue = length //-length to run animation clock-wise
animation.repeatCount = .infinity
animation.duration = 10
shape.add(animation, forKey: "MyAnimation")

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = rectangle
```