# Drawing checkmark with stroke animation in swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation

I have a button in my iOS app and I want to apply a checkmark animation when the user taps it, but I don't have any idea how would I achieve this. If anybody has an idea please help me out.
Below is a sample gif image of the animation I want to create.

[image]

Comment: Quite simple. Sliding a mask would do it.

Comment: If CoreAnimation question, you would [animate `strokeEnd`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42978938/1271826).

Comment: This question looks curiously similar to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66935222/1271826), answered earlier today.

Comment: I need to implement it in my iOS app website is just for refeence for the button

Comment: i just have a button on my ios app and want to apply checkmark animation over it nothing more than that

Comment: I provided a very complete answer to that very question in another post. In fact, you lifted the sample image from my answer.

Comment: I can't mark the question as being a dupe because the OP has not accepted it. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66935002/how-to-apply-checkmark-animation-in-swift/66935222#66935222

Comment: Did my answer answer your question? If so, you should accept it.

Answer (score 3):

To create that animation you can either animate a mask revealing the check mark from left to right, as Matt says, or you can use a `CAShapeLayer` to draw the check-mark, and then animate the `strokeEnd` property of the shape layer.

(The sliding mask approach would always reveal the view's contents from left to right¹, whether the view contained a checkmark or a picture of a kitten. The shape layer stroke approach is specific to drawing shapes using `UIBezierPath` (or the Core Foundation equivalent, `CGPath`), but you can use it to draw complex shapes from beginning to end, even shapes that loop back on themselves. It's not limited to always revealing the view content from left to right.)

As it happens, the image you used in your question is the product of a demo app I created last weekend that uses the `CAShapeLayer` approach.

You can find the complete demo app here:

https://github.com/DuncanMC/AnimateCheckMark.git

In order to do animate the stroke, you'll need to create your check mark as a shape layer. Sample code to create a check mark looks like this:

```
private func checkmarkPath() -> CGPath {
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 5, y: bounds.midY))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 25, y: bounds.midY + 20))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 45, y: bounds.midY - 20))
    return path.cgPath
}
```

(That code isn't very general-purpose. It creates a fixed sized check mark. You might need to modify it to scale the check-mark to fit the view it belongs to.)

Once you have created a shape layer and installed your checkmark in it you need to create an animation that animates the shape layer's strokeEnd property. **That** code might look like this:

```
 This function animates showing or hiding the checkmark view's layer by animating the layer's strokeEnd property.

 - Parameter show: If true, show the checkmark. If false, hide it.
 - Parameter animationDuration: the duration of the animation, in seconds.
 - Parameter animationCurve: Indicates the animation timing curve to use, .linear or .easeInEaseOut
*/
public func animateCheckmarkStrokeEnd(_ show: Bool,
                                      animationDuration: Double = 0.3,
                                      animationCurve: AnimationCurve = .linear) {
    guard let layer = layer as? CAShapeLayer else { return }
    let newStrokeEnd: CGFloat = show ? 1.0 : 0.0
    let oldStrokeEnd: CGFloat = show ? 0.0 : 1.0

    let keyPath = "strokeEnd"
    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: keyPath)
    animation.fromValue = oldStrokeEnd
    animation.toValue = newStrokeEnd
    animation.duration = animationDuration
    let timingFunction: CAMediaTimingFunction
    if animationCurve == .linear {
        timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.linear)
    } else {
        timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeInEaseOut)
    }
    animation.timingFunction = timingFunction
    layer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        layer.strokeEnd = newStrokeEnd
    }
    self.checked = show
}
```

The entire demo app lets you create the checkmark animation as either a stroke animation or a cross-fade, and allows you to use either linear timing or ease-in/ease-out timing. The window for the demo app looks like this:

[image]

---

¹: You could create other mask animations that reveal your view's contents from right to left, top to bottom, from the center out, etc. For the checkmark animation in your question, though, the mask animation you would need would be a left-to-right "wipe" animation.